# im trying to call the number in the list, if you input 0, youll get the 1 right but i dont get it, i dont know what is wrong or missing

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to call the number in the list, if you input 0, you will get the 1 right but i don't get it, i don't know what is wrong or missing.

[image]

here is the screenshot of my code

```
test_grind = [
 [1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9],
 [0]
]    
test_grind = input("test choice: ")
def test_pick():
    if (test_grind == 0):
        print(test_grind[0][0])
```

Comment: You're overwriting `test_grind` by saving the call to `input` with the same variable-name. So once the call to `input` has been done, `test_grind` is no longer a list of lists, it's a string.

Comment: try to create a more concise heading for your question and pull "im trying to call the number in the list, if you input 0, youll get the 1 right but i dont get it, i dont know what is wrong or missing" into your question body.

also as you can see you can just inline code, so its not necessary for the linked image.

Comment: my friend told me the solution and it worked, i added "str" before the input

str(input("test"))